# CartoCSS : Style a road using a road_label rule

Tags: mapbox, cartocss

The parisian ring road (and probably others) usually looks a bit off (especially at low zoom levels), because in OSM it has been created as two independant 'main' roads, instead of one 'highway'.

What I could do is apply my highway style to all the OSM ways of the ring road, using a [osm_id=xxx] selector, but it's going to be a bit tedious.

All the OSM ways of the ring road have a 'road_label' tag with the same 'Boulevard Périphérique Intérieur' value. In this case would it be possible to apply a style on the road, using a road_label property? If so, how?

Thanks !